# After reset of calendar date value using JavaScript, when I click on Submit button the changed date value reset to the previous value before change

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, calendar

I changed the calendar date value using JavaScript, it was successful but when I clicked on Submit button the changed date value reset to the previous value before the change.

Below js I used to change the calendar date:-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver
js.executescript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", driver.findElement(By.xpath(//tr(@id='datepicker')),"2015-06-07")
```

Please let me know how to prevent the date reset.

Comment: It depends, if it's jquery you could try `$(#datepicker').val(date)` and if it's react / angular you can try dispatching an event